# Controlling wrapping on Bootstrap 4 responsive navbar

Tags: bootstrap-4, responsive

I've got a BS4 navbar *nearly* working how I want it, but not quite.

I've got a navbar-brand at the left, and four links at the right.

[Navbar with links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkpFG.png)

At a certain breakpoint, the links disappear to be replaced by the hamburger button.

[Navbar with hamburger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hnhh.png)

If you click the hamburger the links appear below it.

[Hamburger with expanded links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFvmN.png)

That's all how I want it.

If you reduce the window width further, though, the navbar wraps, and the hamburger appears *below* the logo.

[Misplaced hamburger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoiWf.png)

That's bit I don't want. I want the hamburger to stay where it is, and the logo reduce in size (img-fluid).

I can achieve this by adding the flex-nowrap class to the main navbar element. But then that causes a different problem: when you click the hamburger the links appear to the right of it, instead of underneath.

[Misplaced links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WJcw.png)

Is there a way to stop the hamburger from wrapping, while still having the links appearing beneath it when you click on it?

Code below:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/Stack_Overflow_logo.svg" class="img-fluid" style="max-height: 4rem" alt="Logo">
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggleMenu">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="toggleMenu">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-right" href="#">item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-right" href="#">item 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-right" href="#">item 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-right" href="#">item 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by setting a minimum width on the navbar and a maximum width for the navbar-brand.

```css
.navbar{
  min-width: 255px;
}
.navbar-brand {
  max-width: 65%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/Stack_Overflow_logo.svg" class="img-fluid" style="max-height: 4rem" alt="Logo">
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggleMenu">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="toggleMenu">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-right" href="#">item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-right" href="#">item 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-right" href="#">item 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-right" href="#">item 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```